# Java - Thread Sleep - Lock Feature

Tags: java, multithreading

For the below point

- sleep() method of Thread class doesn't relinquish the lock it has acquired.
- With sleep() in Java its not guaranteed that when sleeping thread woke up it will definitely get CPU, instead it will go to Runnable state and fight for CPU with other thread.

If the Current Thread doesnt release the Lock, why it has to go to Runnable State and compete with Other threads for execution

Comment: That second point doesn't have anything to do with the first. Simply, each thread gets its share of the CPU to perform its work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that CPU is a food processor, and a `Thread` is a cook. One cook is cooking cocktail and get lock for objects `martini` and `beer`. Another `Thread` is cooking soup and get lock for `List<Vegetable>`. 
Imagine that both cooks compete for food processor. They have its objects, and they need CPU which could process only one task.

Runnable state means that a cook is ready for using processor (i.e. `Vegetables` are washed or bottle is opened). Any cooker may use food processor regardless how much items he has. Any process could say "I want to use CPU" regardless any lock.